# Having trouble with media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have my code set up right now where I have one div visible from 0-992 pixels browser width, and the other div visible from 993-infinity browser width, and when one div is visible, the other is hidden. The div is the video  in the code. My question is, why is .mobileVideo class still showing at 992 pixels? It is just that one pixel range that is broken, and can't figure a way around it. I hope I explained this clearly, if not please ask what to clarify more. Here's my html and media queries.

```
<section class="promoVid">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>What We Have to Offer</h2>
            <div>
                <span class="decoration_line"></span>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel massa iaculis, posuere augue et, pharetra ipsum. Suspendisse metus ex, pellentesque id dolor in, vehicula varius tortor. Nam auctor ante nisi.</p>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <a class="btn defaultBtn btn-block" href="/services">Services</a>
                </div>
          </div>                       
          <div class="video-responsive"><!--hidden-xs hidden-sm-->
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NmeFmmoqzR4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="mobileVideo"> <!--visible-sm visible-xs-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="videoWrapper">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NmeFmmoqzR4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


 @media (max-width: 992px) {
        .video-responsive {
            display: none!important;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 993px) {
        .mobileVideo {
            display: none!important;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces between your CSS values and `!important` declarations.
`dispaly:none!important` should be `display: none !important`.

Having said that, you should really use `!important` declarations at all, as they provide the maximum level of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. Try to add more specific rules if necessary, though note that a simple `display: none` will suffice in your example.

As for the pixel range, your `max-width` goes **up** to `992`, and the other starts at `993`. For one pixel, this will overlap. Simply set them to use the same value to avoid this. I've gone with `992` in my example.

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .video-responsive {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .mobileVideo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="promoVid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>What We Have to Offer</h2>
        <div>
          <span class="decoration_line"></span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel massa iaculis, posuere augue et, pharetra ipsum. Suspendisse metus ex, pellentesque id dolor in, vehicula varius tortor. Nam auctor ante nisi.</p>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
          <a class="btn defaultBtn btn-block" href="/services">Services</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="video-responsive">
        <!--hidden-xs hidden-sm-->
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NmeFmmoqzR4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="mobileVideo">
  <!--visible-sm visible-xs-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NmeFmmoqzR4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not it, the queries still work without the spaces, it's just that one pixel range that is broken.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that initially. You simply need to set them to use the same value :)